# Gradle sync failed: Cause: https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3.2-all.zip

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, updates

Platform and Plugin Updates in Android Studio and 
I get the error:

```
Gradle sync failed: Cause: https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3.2-all.zip
```

In File > Project structure > Project Gradle version: 2.3.2/ Android plugin version 2.3.2

My Gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
}
}

 allprojects {
   repositories {
      jcenter()
   }
 }

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Comment: The problem obviously is with gradle wrapper setup not with build.gradle... There was no gradle version 2.3.2 and gradle version is not android plugin version....  You should try 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Android studio is able to reach the internet (for example if you're behind a proxy)

Comment: I have no proxy and the internt should be fine because I finished updating

Answer (score 0):

I updated the `distributionUrl` in gradle-wrapper.properties file  in the project cradle Scripts to a later release and existed in my .gradle directory in `/username/.gradle/wrapper/dists`

my `/username/.gradle/wrapper/dists` had

1. gradle-3.5.3-all
2. gradle-5.4.1-all
3. gradle-5.6.2-all
4. gradle-6.0.1-all

I got the above  error when my `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5.3-all.zip`
I changed it to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip`

And the build was successful.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps :download gradle by->
click on Tools --> Android --> Sync Project with Gradle Files from the Android Studio menu bar.

Comment: It stays the same

Comment: save your project and and when done firstly update repositories in SDK manager and then see the error : {cause}.

Comment: Nothing stays the same :(